# Quelle/que fut la réaction de ton employeur à l’annonce de ta démission?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Est-ce que les deux pronoms sont corrects dans la phrase en titre?

Comment: Ton et ta? Mais en parlant, Je dirais: Quelle a été

Comment: @Lambie Dans cet esprit ce serait plutôt quelle et quel, et non quelle et que?

Comment: Si jamais j’ai bien saisi ton allusion.

Comment: Pour te dire la vérité, sans faire des recherches, je ne sais pas. Je sais seulement le dire. En parlant, on n'entend pas la différence. :)

Comment: Merci pour tes commentaires Lambie.

Comment: Possiblement une nuance syntaxique [ici](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) ; avec _que_ ça ressemble à _en quoi elle consiste cette réaction-là_ tandis que avec _quelle_ on n'est pas « encadré » de la même manière par l'interrogation.

Comment: Pourquoi 'fut' ?

Comment: @Dimitris … parce que la réaction s'est produite dans une action terminée.

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques … de plus, à l'oreille, on rattache *quelle* à *réaction* en conformité avec *quel/quelle* https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quel

Comment: @Personne : Je connais ça:-)! Dans quel context utilise-t-on le passé simple ? Travaillant dans un milieu académique depuis des années, je ne me souviens pas avoir jamais écouté quelqu'un utiliser le passé simple dans son discours.

Comment: @Dimitris C'est vrai, mais JL Frenette privilégie toujours un registre très soutenu. Dans le langage parlé courant, ça aurait pu être : *Ton patron, il l'a pris comment que tu files ta dem' ?* PS: *jamais entendu*, pas *jamais écouté*.

Comment: @Dimitris … peu souvent, cependant ce n'était pas au travail, mais dans des discussions amicales dites par des personnes obligées de soigner leur expression orale, médecins, enseignants, comédiens …

Comment: @Dimitris Le passé simple *pourrait* s'utiliser par un prof qui donne un cours magistral en amphithéâtre, par exemple. Evidemment, cela n'est pas "conversationnel". Ou bien dans d'autres présentations du même genre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Mise en caractères gras due à user LPH*)

*QUEL*

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quel))
> Pronom interrogatif
> (Avec le verbe être) **Interroge sur l’identité ou la qualité du sujet.**
> ♦ Quel est donc ton problème ?
> ♦ Quel est cet homme qui saura débrouiller tout ça ?
> ♦ Quel est-il, celui qui viendra à ma rencontre ?

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quel)) Rem. 1. Lorsque le suj. est un pron. pers. qui n'est pas de la 3e pers., le tour est rare: Qui sommes-nous? ou plutôt: quels sommes-nous, nous autres d'aujourd'hui, qui renonçons, sans même en avoir conscience, à nommer la vertu, et peut-être, à sentir vivre en nous l'idée auguste que ce nom rappelait jadis dans toute sa force? (Valéry, Variété IV, 1938, p. 172). 2. *Quel* peut être attribut de l'obj.: Tu sauras pour quel on me tient. Ô gnome, Et tu pourras savoir par le menu Si j'ai l'âme gaillarde, et pour quel on me nomme (Moréas, Pèlerin pass., 1891, p. 81).
> − [**L'interr. porte sur l'inanimé**]
> [***Quel* interroge sur la détermination ou sur la qualité**]
> ♦ Tu pleures, ô mon roi! Quelle est donc ta souffrance? De ma fidélité tu connais la constance! (Moréas, Iphigénie, 1900, i, 1, p. 12).
> ♦ Quelles sont ces images qui pénètrent l'enfant d'un trouble passionné? Jamais il ne les avait vues; et pourtant il les connaissait: il les a reconnues (Rolland, J.-Chr., Aube, 1904, p. 69).
> ♦ Mon anxiété se tournait plus que jamais vers la Belgique. Quelle serait son attitude? Le roi Albert a donné trop de preuves de sa loyauté à la cause alliée pour qu'il ne soit pas possible de dire aujourd'hui que, par ses attaches de famille et sa forme d'esprit, on pouvait craindre de le voir se tourner vers nos ennemis (Joffre, Mém., t. 1, 1931, p. 215).

> ([Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9Q0167)) I. Pronom interrogatif.
> Pour former une question **qui implique un choix dans un ensemble**. Lequel, qui. Quelle est la meilleure ? Elle cherche à savoir quelle est la plus fidèle de ces deux traductions. Vieilli. Quel de ses tableaux veut-il vendre ? (dans cette construction, on emploie aujourd’hui Lequel).

([réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_actes_des_ap%C3%B4tres/9X-3DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelle+f%C3%BBt+leur%22&pg=PT115&printsec=frontcover)) Quelle fut leur attitude envers l'homme que Dieu avait choisi à cet effet ?

([réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jordanie_4/T71_fRmlwtQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelle+f%C3%BBt+leur%22&pg=PT427&printsec=frontcover)) Quelle fut leur influence sur l'islam ?

([réf. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Je_donne_du_sens_%C3%A0_ma_vie/kq3TDgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelle+aurait+%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22&pg=PA151&printsec=frontcover)) Quelle aurait été ma vie ?

([réf. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Personne_ne_m_aurait_cru_alors_je_me_sui/5iinCQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelle+aurait+%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT107&printsec=frontcover)) Quelle aurait été ma réaction ? Je ne sais pas, mais si j'avais ressenti de la haine, j'aurais été très déçu et affligé.

*QUE*

([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que))
Pronom interrogatif, Invariable
**Pronom interrogatif pour l’objet direct inanimé**
♦ Que veux-tu ?
♦ Qu’attendez-vous ?
♦ Que diable dites-vous là ?

> ([Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9Q0160)) Le pronom interrogatif *Que* représente toujours une chose et s’emploie dans les propositions interrogatives directes et les propositions interrogatives indirectes à l’infinitif, où il occupe différentes fonctions. Dans les constructions où le pronom interrogatif est précédé d’une préposition, on emploie la forme tonique *Quoi* et non *Que*.

> ([Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/pronoms-interrogatifs)) Dans certaines tournures de phrases, il peut représenter un être animé en fonction attribut à la place de qui :
> Que devient-il ? (attribut)

([réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Qu_%C3%A9tait_ce/744QAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22qu%27%C3%A9tait%22&dq=%22qu%27%C3%A9tait%22&printsec=frontcover)) Qu'était-ce ?

([réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Qu_%C3%A9tait_la_b%C3%AAte_du_G%C3%A9vaudan/YkiAQwAACAAJ?hl=fr)) Qu'était la bête du Gévaudan?

([réf. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_Afrique_en_100_questions/PCwXEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22qu%27a+%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22&printsec=frontcover)) Qu’a été, ou qu’est toujours, la Françafrique ?

---

Les deux sont corrects, puisque « réaction » est une chose. La différence tient à une remarque dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie à propos de « quel » ; c'est celle-ci (que l'on trouve ci-dessus) : « *Pour former une question qui implique un choix dans un ensemble* » ; cette idée est en rapport avec la notion d'identification. C'est pour cela, par exemple, que le cas d'illustration utilisé supra, « Qu'était la bête du Gévaudan ? », ferait une très étrange impression si on l'écrivait « Quelle était la bête du Gévaudan ? ».  Donc, si on utilise « que », on émet une question générale sur la nature de la réaction, alors que si on utilise « quelle » on présuppose des réactions attendues parmi lesquelles l'une ou l'autre doit être celle qui a résulté ; évidemment, qu'il y ait lieu de supposer qu'il existe un tel ensemble  plus ou moins bien défini est sujet à contestation dans ce contexte de réactions à une démission, mais le locuteur le laisse entendre, et ça peut paraitre plausible.

« Quel » peut être difficile à justifier dans caertains cas, mais dans d'autres il s'impose.

- Il me semble, par exemple, que l'on ne dirait pas « [Qu'a été/ Que fut] son choix parmi les candidats ? » mais « [Quel a été/Quel fut] son choix parmi les candidats ? ».